# pymysql записывает русский текст некорректно в БД

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, charset, pymysql

Здравствуйте! Проблема состоит в следующем:
Есть парсер таблиц с сайта на python 3, который получает значения ячеек и кладет в таблицу на удаленном сервере. Для поиска по странице сайта используется библиотека BeautifulSoup. Все значения парсер находит нормально, для проверки записываю результат в файл и там все хорошо, но когда пытаюсь записать в базу данных, то появляется следующий warning: `Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\x98\\xD0\\xBD\\xD1\\x82\\xD0...' for column 'description' at row 1")`
 Кодировка таблицы в базе utf-8, кодировка страницы которую парсим - windows-1251. Помогите справиться с проблемой, русский текст сейчас в базу записывается в виде: `РњРѕРґРµР»СЊ`

Ниже функция получения кода страницы:

```
def get_html(url):
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
return response.read()
```

А вот функция, которая результат добавляет в БД:

```
def add_to_db(chars, desc):
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
    port=3307, 
    user='***',
    password='***',
    db='***',
    charset='utf8', 
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

global _id
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`id_cat`, `characteristics`, `description`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (_id, chars, desc))
conn.commit()
```

Кроме приведенных отрывков кода остался только парсер, но мне кажется он не имеет ценности в решении данного вопроса...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`id_cat`, `characteristics`, `description`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (_id, chars.encode('utf8'), desc.encode('utf8')))
conn.commit()
```